# Where to store access token securely in UWP application?

Tags: security, uwp, access-token, desktop-application

Local storage is not right place to store tokens. But [this](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/05/10/getting-started-storing-app-data-locally/) blog post says LocalCache is generally the right location. If I store in LocalCache using DPAPI, Does this enough secure?

Does PasswordVault is good place to store it?

How can I store token securely so that outside this application token is not accessible?

Comment: If you store the token with LocalSettings,  it will store in the app's local data, it is not accessible outside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would definitely recommend storing confidential information like an Access Token in the `PasswordVault` as `LocalSettings` are not encrypted and are accessible quite easily from the app's package folder in `AppData`.

Although `PasswordVault` has a bit odd API, you can still easily use it to store the token:

```
var passwordVault = new PasswordVault();
passwordVault.Add(new PasswordCredential("Resource", "UserName", accessToken));
```

In your case, you most likely care only about the access token, so the "resource" and "user name" may be just arbitrary constants. Retrieving the token is easy as well:

```
//find credentials in the store            
PasswordCredential? credential = null;

try
{
   // Try to get an existing credential from the vault.
   credential = _passwordVault.Retrieve("Resource", "UserName");
}
catch (Exception)
{
   // When there is no matching resource an error occurs, which we ignore.
}
credential?.RetrievePassword();
return credential?.Password;
```

Note the use of `try..catch`. This is because the vault throws if given resource/user name combo is not found (which could even happen when user manually deletes the entry in system Credential Manager.

Another advantage of `PasswordVault` is that credentials are synced across devices (although this feature may be going away in future versions).

Answer (score 0):

> Where to store access token securely in UWP application?

In general, we often store access token with [`ApplicationData.LocalSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings?view=winrt-19041) class that place settings container in the local app data store. You could use it like the following.

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

// Create a simple setting.
localSettings.Values["accesstoken"] = token;

// Read data from a simple setting.
Object value = localSettings.Values["accesstoken"];

if (value == null)
{
    // No data.
}
else
{
    // Access data in value.
}
```

And if you want to store access token securely. The Windows Runtime provides the `PasswordVault` class to securely store credentials. for more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=winrt-19041).